# Abstract class and polymorphism issue

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, polymorphism, abstract-class

I am trying to do the following:

```
public abstract class MyBaseFragment extends Fragment {
    private FloatingActionButton fab;

    protected void initFab(View contentView, int resourceId) {
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) contentView.findViewById(resourceId);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchDetailsDialogFragment(new Animal());
            }
        });
    }

    private void launchDetailsDialogFragment(Animal animal) {
        //... 
    }
}
```

The key point here being the line about making a new Animal.

I have various types of Animals -- Cat, Dog, etc. The page about Cats, the page about Dogs, etc, they will all extend MyBaseFragment. So clicking the FloatingActionButton on the Cat page will execute a function that passes in a new Cat() to the DialogFragment where you can edit its details. Same for Dogs. But each details DialogFragment is a little different, since Cats and Dogs have different properties from each other even though they are both Animals.

However I don't know how to apply polymorphism here. Right now all MyBaseFragment knows is that it will make a new Animal, but really I want it to make a new Cat, or a new Dog, etc, depending on where I am extending the base fragment.

How do I do this?

Comment: I am assuming that the extending classes know which animal to use, so when they are calling initFab() why don't they pass in the required animal?

Comment: @AshFrench The Cat page for example has a list of cats. You click a cat, you can edit its details (initialized from a db). But if you click the add button, it brings up the same details dialog, just with a new/fresh Cat object (so all fields are blank). I am trying to use an abstract class to implement features that are common to all pages, but it still needs to be able to launch unique things depending on the situation.

Comment: well have you considered having an abstract method that returns an Animal, that each class implements, then you could do `launchDetailsDialogFragment(getNewAnimal())`

Comment: I don't understand, what would getNewAnimal() be, where would it be implemented, and how would it know which animal to get?

Comment: in your abstract class have `abstract protected Animal getNewAnimal();` Then in your `CatFragment extends MyBaseFragment` you implement `getNewAnimal()` where it returns an `new Cat()` and so on for the other classes

Comment: @Raghunandan Possibly... is there a way to use instanceOf() instead of some kind of extra tag like RECTANGLE or CIRCLE? Like getAnimal() returns Cat if the object passed in was a Cat, etc?

Comment: @Raghunandan Well for example I'd have something like `public class CatMainFragment extends MyBaseFragment {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the called method abstract ad have each concrete class fill in its own implementation

```
public abstract class MyBaseFragment extends Fragment {
    private FloatingActionButton fab;

    protected void initFab(View contentView, int resourceId) {
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) contentView.findViewById(resourceId);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchDetailsDialogFragment();
            }
        });
    }

    protected abstract void launchDetailsDialogFragment();
}
```

Comment: Is there a difference between saying `private void launchDetailsDialogFragment()` and `private abstract void launchDetailsDialogFragment();`?

Comment: If you use abstract you cannot have default implementation. Without abstract you can.

Comment: But if you just type `private void launchDetailsDialogFragment();` the compiler says it's missing a body

Comment: @ArukaJ methods are not abstract, classes are. Since your class is already abstract, so no body method are accepted

Comment: I am really confused. If you literally take the code you have written above, the compiler doesn't like it.

Comment: You cannot have private and abstract together

Comment: @SamuelRobert Right -- but the code above just has private void with no abstract and no method body, inside an abstract class

Comment: My bad. Make the method not private. If its private, it cannot be overidden which  defeats the whole point hence the compiler error. Updating the answer

Comment: Change the signature to protected abstract void launchDetailsDialogFragment();

Comment: Right, I think it would need to be protected abstract void (protected so it can be seen by a child class, and abstract so the child class has to implement it)

Comment: @FunkyIdol"methods are not abstract, classes are. Since your class is already abstract, so no body method are accepted" This statement is wrong.

Comment: The answer of yours disproves that.

Comment: @SamuelRobert You are right. I got confused between method definition on abstract class and an interface. Thanks for the quick reminder lesson :)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can process families of objects by using 'Visitor' pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Make `launchDetailsDialogFragment` abstract:

```
protected abstract void launchDetailsDialogFragment();
```

And implement it in the subclasses like you want.

Comment: Is there a difference between saying `protected void launchDetailsDialogFragment()` and `protected abstract void launchDetailsDialogFragment();`? Or using private instead of protected?

Comment: @ArukaJ yes. `abstract` keyword means that this function transfers its implementation to the classes that will extend your base class.

Comment: `abstract` mandates all children classes to implement this method. Without `abstract` they could simply not override it and leave it empty.

Comment: @m0skit0 But without abstract you'd have to do something like `protected void someFunction() {}` right? And then you can do `@Override` from a child class if you want to implement it

Comment: Right. It all depends if you wanna force children classes to implement the method or a default method in parent class would do. Btw `@Override` is optional in both cases (but recommended).

Answer (score 0):

You must let the MyBaseFragment specific implementations decide which animal to instantiate while launching the detail fragment.As far as I can understand the MyBaseFragment abstract class only knows that there should be a detailfragment which should be launched on click event of fabbutton, it does not know of the 
the type of fragment which should be launched.This would be decided by the
specific implementation of the fragment. So, mark the method responsible for creating the detailfragment as protected abstract and override them in the specific implementations to create the specific animal.